# XZing com xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, qrcode, código-de-barras

Olá
Estou tentando implementar a leitura de código de barras no meu app Xamarin.Forms de acordo com a documentação.

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile , mas quando tento executar o código abaixo

```
private async void ExecuteBuscaInventarioCommand()
{
    try
    {
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
        var result = await scanner.Scan();

        if (result != null)
            Codigo = result.Text;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ops!", ex.Message, "Ok");
    }
}
```

recebo a mensagem  `System.NotSupportedException: Use the platform specific implementation instead!`

Na documentação diz para eu adicionar um componente de suporte android mas o  link que está quebrado...

No construtor eu coloquei isso

```
MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
```

mas o Initialize não é reconhecido.

Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39354186/6809703

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No projeto android você adicionou esse trecho na activity ?

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
```

E fez o override do método OnRequestPermissionsResult ?

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{ 
global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Dê uma olhada no [projeto no github](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) e veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado
De fato faltou o ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
Esta 100% agora